# Right Click on ASP.Net Treeview selects the Node (NOT Windows Forms)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview, contextmenu

I've been googling in circles for hours now but can only find answers relating to WinForms and not ASP.NET web pages.

I would like my ASP Treeview to select the node that is being right clicked (so that I can use my ContextMenu without having to left click a node first)

Is this possible? It feels like it should be? I'm trying to avoid a situation where they have a subfolder open and selected but then right click on a child node and edit but the subfolder is still selected so it edits that

Comment: I don't have a example, but then again one big reason why you can't find examples is that with the rise of smartphones, and boatloads of people using tablets, then right click context menus are VERY difficult on touch based devices. So, right click context menus where rather popular on desktop software - on web based then no so much. If you have a right click context working after clicking on the node to expand, then that's quite good, but as you note not ideal.

Comment: Good point although I'm developing the web side of a smartphone app so it is okay to use it here (and is necessary). Hopefully someone will have an answer